# Cambridge Maths Tripos Papers

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Does anyone know where I can find Cambridge Maths Tripos Papers for the 1980s?

Comment: welcome to the site. Have you taken the tour of the site

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find them in the university library.

Comment: Yeah its a great question. There is a website http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/ Search around on the same site there are other exam papers organized by subject.

Comment: Why do you need them? College libraries used to have old papers and the faculty library, but I wouldn't want to guess how far back.

Comment: This is a question I'd like an answer too as well (which is why I gave an upvote). One reason for asking a question like this is not living in Cambridge (as many people do not) and therefore not having access to college libraries and the faculty library.

Answer (score 1):

Past tripos papers for dates before those listed on the website tend to be hard (if not impossible) to get access to. If you are a member of the university, there are a few possibilities. Gareth Taylor has some on his site (only available to members of the university) but they only go back a few more years than the ones on the faculty website. Other options are to look in the faculty library or the university library. There may also be copies in college libraries and (if you are a maths student) your DoS may have some.